# How can set pop-up menu position in QML

Tags: menu, qml, qt5, popupmenu

I want to fix the position of pop-up menu in QML. When I click on a setting button,I want the pop-up menu will display at the fixed position. I did it by a day but can't. How can I do it in QML. Also, I want to change the size of menu item(width and Height).

Hope your help!

Answer (score 2):

That depends on `QtQuick.Controls` version.

In `2.0` you can define size and position(and even more - you must do)

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
//import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window
{
    id: window
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            menu.x = (window.width - menu.width) / 2
            menu.y = (window.height - menu.height) / 2
            //menu.__popup(Qt.rect(200,200,100,100),0,0);
            menu.open();
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: menu
        MenuItem { text: "item1" }
        MenuItem { text: "item2"; }
        MenuItem { text: "item3"; height: 100 }
    }
}
```

In `1.4` (see commented lines) you can try `Menu.__popup()` but this function is private and the behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: I use version 1.4. I can't set width & height in MenuItem in normal. But function __popup is OK. You save my day!

Comment: I met a problem with popup menu. Every time I popup menu display, the memory increase(~15 Mb in my computer) and not decrease when menu close. And application crash after many times menu displays.

Comment: try to use `popup()`. is it increase the memory too?

Comment: Yes, it increase too. Also, menu position is not set in popup() function.

Comment: Or, in 1.4 `popup()` just brings up the menu at the mouse position and nothing more. But the memory leaking is not good. Try to test it with only `popup()` call, without any program logic. Maybe the memory leak isn't relate to `popup()`

Comment: I using your source and test but the memory still increase. It seem a Qt bug :(