# Open menu in certain x and y position on screen

Tags: qt, qml

I have this menu in a main.qml file:

```
    Menu {
            id: recentFilesSubMenu
            title: qsTr("Recent Files")
            enabled: recentFilesInstantiator.count > 0

            Instantiator {
                id: recentFilesInstantiator
                model: settings.recentFiles
                delegate: MenuItem {
                    text: settings.displayableFilePath(modelData)
                    onTriggered: loadFile(modelData)
                }

                onObjectAdded: recentFilesSubMenu.insertItem(index, object)
                onObjectRemoved: recentFilesSubMenu.removeItem(object)
            }

            MenuSeparator {}

            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Clear Recent Files")
                
                onTriggered: settings.clearRecentFiles()
            }
          }
```

Which is open when I click to

```
    ListDelegate {
            id: recentitemsItem
            text: i18n("Recent Items")                
            highlight: delegateHighlight              
                               
                onClicked: {                   
                    
                    recentFilesSubMenu.open();                       
                    
                }
    }
```

The problem is that I want to open it in a certain x, y position on screen not where the mouse pointer is. How can I do this in qml .I've tried setting an x and y position but I can not assign it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can set pop-up menu position in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580053/how-can-set-pop-up-menu-position-in-qml)

Comment: Hi.Unfortunately does not.I have already tried this answer but I can not assign x and y position for menu.

Answer (score 0):

The following example works as expected:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Test"
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var x = window.width / 2 - menu.width / 2;
            var y = window.height / 2 - menu.height / 2;
            menu.x = x;
            menu.y = y;
            menu.open();
            
            //menu.popup(x, y); // or use this line instead of previous 3 ones
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: menu
        MenuItem {
            text: "Item1"
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Item2"
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Item3"
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work it means that you do something wrong:

- you use Qt < 5.7
- you call to popup() without arguments
- you don't set x and y when use open()

Comment: In my case it doesn't work.I checked all the reasons you mention and I am not doing something wrong.But there is a difference between my case and your example.In my case there is no `ApplicationWindow` as  parent item.The hierarchy is Item -> ColumnLayout -> Menu as menuitem in ColumnLayout.

Comment: I rewrote the code from scratch, and now the hierarchy is MouseArea ->Menu. The menu is working now.